# value of type 'UIpageControl' has no member 'currentpage'

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

In my app I am using `UICollectionView` with **pagecontroll**. Now I want to update `UIPageControll` indecator on scrolling collectionview.

Now issue is that `pagecontroll.currentpage` is not available.

So is there any possible solution for update `UIPageControll` indicator.
**Note** : I am using **iOS10** **Swift**

[image]

```
 func didChangePageControlValue() {
    tutorialPageViewController?.scrollToViewController(index: pageControl.currentPage)
}
```

Comment: Are using page conteoller or page ctrl?

Comment: Please share your code and clearly point out where is the problem.

Comment: i am using pagecontrol @Aisha

Comment: So how it has not property. Should I send you a refernce ??? Will that work for u??